# Issues while editing an EditText during a focus change

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two `EditTexts` for a username and password, each having the text *"ENTER A USERNAME"* and *"ENTER A PASSWORD"* respectively, as their default text.

Their text colors are a light gray. Now when they get focused they're supposed to change text colors as well as the password edittext's inputType to a password type (on top of other things but that works).

It successfully changes the text color to black at first but fails to change back and the inputType never changes.

Please suggest me where I am lacking, below is my code:

```
OnFocusChangeListener pwListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                //if it has focus then clear the text and make text black
                if(((EditText) v).getText().toString().compareTo(getString(R.string.passwordField)) == 0) {
                    ((EditText) v).setTextColor(R.color.Black);
                    ((EditText) v).setText(R.string.blank);
                    ((EditText) v).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                }
            } else if(!hasFocus) {
                //if it loses focus and nothing was inputed then change back to default
                if(isEmpty(((EditText) v).getText().toString())) {
                    ((EditText) v).setTextColor(R.color.TextInput);
                    ((EditText) v).setText(R.string.passwordField);
                    ((EditText) v).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Thats the passwords edit text and this is its XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:text="@string/passwordField"
    android:textColor="@color/TextInput"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ems="10" >
 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you dont set the ENTER A USERNAME" and "ENTER A PASSWORD" as hint text in Edittext using

```
android:hint="Enter User Name"
```

It will automatically disappear when user clicked on Edittext.

Comment: Haha wow that would've saved me so much time if I only knew of that sooner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Xml use [Hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable_hint) property to set values as default.

like:

`android:hint="@string/username"`

`android:hint="@string/password"`

Instead

`android:text="@string/username"`

`android:text="@string/password"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:hint="@string/passwordField"
```

instead of

```
android:text="@string/passwordField"
```

and do same in username